# How support requesting refresh_token with offline_access scope

Tags: spring-authorization-server

I am working on an implementation of spring-authorization-server and want to add support for the `offline_access` scope as described in the [openid-connect rfc](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#OfflineAccess). When the `offline_access` scope is requested, then a `refresh_token` is issued.

Currently the spring-authorization-server project issues a refresh token when a RegisteredClient contains `AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN`. I would like to change this behavior so that the the client must request the `offline_access` scope in order for a refresh token to be issued.

What is the best way to add support for this? Initially, I copied all of the code from `OAuth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider` into my own custom implementation and edited [the conditional statement](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/main/oauth2-authorization-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/authentication/OAuth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.java#L216) that determines whether or not refresh token should be issued. However, I would like to avoid copying and overriding this for maintainability reasons.

Comment: Can you please provide additional details? Are you trying to support `refresh_token` for a public client? See [#297](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297).

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg No, I do not want to issue refresh token to public clients.  I am trying to issue refresh token only when a scope named `offline_access` is requested. The spring-authorization-server project issues a refresh token when a RegisteredClient contains `AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN`. I would like to issue refresh tokens to clients only when the client requests the `offline_access` scope, as described in the openid-connect rfc.

Comment: Ohhh, I see! Ok. In that case, I think the ability to customize that is missing so it would be good to [open an enhancement request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/new/choose) for that.

Comment: I opened a github issue for this enhancement here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/1422